# Search newbie, should I use Full Text or not? (SQL Server 2008 Express R2)

Tags: asp.net, sql, full-text-search

For a website I'm creating I need to search a few tables like Articles, Products and maybe the `ForumThread` and `ForumPosts` tables. I now have a very simple LIKE search query for each of these tables `title` columns `VARCHAR(255)`. The title column is indexed too.

In the future however I want to look in `Description` fields too which are `VARCHAR(Max)` and I'm guessing this will be very slow when there's lots of records.

Now I came across full text search and have the following questions about it:

- Will full text search speed up these kind of simple search operations?
- Can I still use a LIKE query in similar ways or do I need to rewrite all search queries?
- Maybe not full text search related but how can I search in multiple tables? I'm now querying each table one by one.
- If I enable full text search, will this eat more RAM (Since I'm on a 1 GB RAM VPS right now)

As you can see I have absolutely no experience with this, and even after reading theory I'm still a little confused about what it really does.

I hope someone can give me a little guidance on this,

Thank you for your time.

Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: As an aside: you might look at the following: http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2007/05/normalizing_sql.html

Answer (score 2):

The big problem with your LIKE-based queries is that they almost certainly can't use normal indexes.  So it won't do you any good to add an index on the description column to help with performance.  Full Text queries consist of two parts: *`1)`* changing your query to use (for example) the CONTAINS() keyword instead of LIKE and *`2)`*  creating a different kind of index that the queries using these keywords will be able to take advantage of.

Here's the thing:  it's not just the size of the field that determines whether full text will have a big impact.  It's also the number of rows.  You may have a simple nvarchar(100) that's only expected to hold a short phrase, but if you have to search millions of rows full text can still search this faster.  The key there is the "have to search" part - if you have other filters that can significantly limit the working set, your LIKE query might still do fine.  Another scenario is an nvarchar(max) field with only a few dozen rows, but each of those records has as much text as a novel.  In this case, you'll still want to use a full text index.

There are two other important considerations for full text searches.  One is that they tend to hog disk space.  This isn't hugely important for most databases, but it is worth mentioning.  The other is that they often need to be manually re-calculated, such that an article isn't ready for searching the moment it's added to the DB.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative that is somewhere between full-text searching and simple LIKE searches that will give you much better performance, some weighting ability, and also simplify searching multiple tables, is to build your own keyword index, e.g. create a table:

```
keyword count tableid columnid rowid
------- ----- ------- -------- -----
varchar int   int     int      int
```

You would of course need triggers or a service of some kind to keep this up to date, but what you end up with is a lightweight cross reference of the counts of all relevant keywords and where they appear. Your search queries then only need to look up the keywords in this index.

This only works for keywords, though, so if you want to let people search on phrases it won't work. You'll also have to incorporate logic to deal with things like plurals and irrelevant words. On the other hand it is extremely fast. If performance is becoming a problem for LIKE searches and you need more than just keywords searching, full-text searching is probably the best way to go.

Comment: I implemented this for something a long time ago using MySql because it lacked any kind of text searching at the time, but I think it has applications no matter what. A good implementation would be optimized by using hashes instead of actual keywords and normalizing so you kept a table of just all keywords (or hashes), then another table that stored the actual data about counts where they appear. The 2nd table will be long, but since it's all numbers, queries are extremely fast.

Answer (score 0):

Full-text search is really intended for when your application needs to do intensive searching of BIG blocks of text rather than simple fields of text for storing names, descriptions etc.

For example I've used it for such things as quickily searching through the content of books/CVs  - it actually creates word-by-word indexes of all the content stored and will probably be overkill if you're not working with massive bits of text.

One design change you could make instead is to use nVarchar(Max) instead of Varchar - this gives you the ability to handle Unicode text (from most known human alphabet systems) and should be large enough for your needs as outlined above.